# Formatting my json in my C# app in a specific way

Tags: c#, arrays, json

I am working on a C# app to work with a 3rd party vendor. They've requested that our JSON be formatted as such (note the "owner" array value)

```
var good =
{
    "id": "0DE570C8-E578-48A9-B22A-F95BC6211B4F",
    "make": "Subaru",
    "index": "Forester",
    "year": "2013",
    "owner": 
    [
        {
            "First": "Bob", 
            "Last": "Smith"
        }
    ]
}
```

In my code, I am unable to get the formatting correct. I am able to produce valid C#, but it doesn't add "owner" as an array and any attempt to make it an array (e.g. adding "[]" after the "new" produces an error ("The name 'x' does not exist in the current context"). Here is my attempted C# code:

```
var car = new
{
    id = "0DE570C8-E578-48A9-B22A-F95BC6211B4F",
    make = "Subaru",
    model = "Forester",
    year = "2013",
    Owner = new
    {
        First = "Bob",
        Last = "Smith"
    }
};
```

I tried making a "Car" class and tried using an anonymous type.

Answer (score 5):

Your `JSON` field for **owner** is an `array` and in your code you assign it as an object so you need to assign **owner** to an array like below:

```
var car = new
{
    id = "0DE570C8-E578-48A9-B22A-F95BC6211B4F",
    make = "Subaru",
    model = "Forester",
    year = "2013",
    Owner = new[]
    {
        new { First = "Bob", Last = "Smith" }
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you, that was it. Seems so simple, but it stumped me. :) Thanks again